# wondering if ionic 3 livereload on device is possible

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am working on ionic app and everything works fine however, this app also has to take a photo using device camera. That means I have to deploy my app on the phone(iPhone). To do that I am using `ionic cordova build ios --prod` command to build it and then I use xcode to deploy on the phone. But I am facing some issues so in order to debug I need to see errors where things are going wrong. So my question is that is there a way to livereload my app on the phone while accessing its physical features and debug my code?

Answer (score 0):

You can run like this:

```
   ionic cordova run ios --device --prod -lcs
```

Comment: This returns `Code Signing Error: Signing for "ProjectName" requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor.`. I normally add development team and signature in xcode. Since it does not prompt me to xcode can I do that in my code configuration file somewhere?